# Difficulty setting menu item bitmaps from CImageList

Tags: c++, mfc, menuitem, imagelist

I have a menu which prompts in a certain situation.
and i have a bitmap image which contains the icons i want to add to the menu.
first, i loaded the image list as following:

```
CImageList imageList;
imageList.Create(18, 16, ILC_COLOR24|ILC_MASK, 0, 0)
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDR_CL2_TAB_MENU_OPTIONS);
imageList.Add(&bitmap, RGB(192, 192, 192));
```

second, i tried to extract the bitmaps to add to the menu using the following

```
IMAGEINFO imgInfo;
ImgList.GetImageInfo( nBmpNo, &imgInfo );
pMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(iItem, MF_BYPOSITION, CBitmap::FromHandle( imgInfo.hbmImage ), NULL);
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work so i tried the code written here 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4673/Extracting-Single-Images-from-a-CImageList-object

but it only gives me black icons in the menu.
here is my complete function to show the menu:

```
void CMainFrame::ShowTabOptions(CPoint point)
{
  CMenu Menu, *pMenu = NULL;

  if (!Menu.LoadMenu (IDR_POPUP_TAB_OPTIONS))
    return;

  pMenu = Menu.GetSubMenu(0);
  if (NULL == pMenu)
    return;

  CImageList imageList;
  if(!imageList.Create(18, 16, ILC_COLOR24|ILC_MASK, 0, 0))
    return;

  CBitmap bitmap;
  bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDR_CL2_TAB_MENU_OPTIONS);
  imageList.Add(&bitmap, RGB(192, 192, 192));

  CArray<CBitmap*, CBitmap*> bitmapArray;
  CBitmap b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
  bitmapArray.Add(&b1);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b2);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b3);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b4);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b5);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b6);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b7);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b8);
  bitmapArray.Add(&b9);

  for (int iItem = 0; iItem < 9; iItem++)
  {
    imageList.Copy( 0, iItem, ILCF_SWAP );

    IMAGEINFO imageInfo;
    imageList.GetImageInfo(0,&imageInfo);
    CDC dc; 
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC (GetWindowDC()); 
    CRect rect (imageInfo.rcImage);

    bitmapArray.GetAt(iItem)->CreateCompatibleBitmap (this->GetWindowDC(), rect.Width (), rect.Height ());

    CBitmap* pOldBmp = dc.SelectObject (bitmapArray.GetAt(iItem));
    imageList.DrawIndirect (&dc, 0, CPoint (0, 0), CSize (rect.Width (), rect.Height ()), CPoint (0, 0)/*, ILD_NORMAL, SRCCOPY, RGB(255, 255, 255)*/);
    dc.SelectObject (pOldBmp);

    pMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(iItem, MF_BYPOSITION, bitmapArray.GetAt(iItem), NULL);
  }


  pMenu->TrackPopupMenu (TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_VCENTERALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, this, NULL);
  Menu.DestroyMenu ();

  for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < bitmapArray.GetCount(); iIndex ++)
  {
    bitmapArray.GetAt(iIndex)->DeleteObject();
  }
}
```

Could anyone tell me what am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Bitmap != icon. Icons have transparency information, either by way of an image mask, or by storing a PNG image. Bitmaps, on the other hand, just contain image data. Part of that data can be interpreted as (alpha) transparency information, but you have to be explicit about it.

Comment: @IInspectable
Thanks for your comment.
if i changed the bitmap extension to PNG or Icon how can i load them and send them to the menu?
could you please give me a coding hint?

Comment: You'll find all the information you need in the MSDN ([Image List Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/image-list-reference)).

Comment: @IInspectable
the only function that sets the menu item icon is `SetMenuItemBitmaps` which takes a bitmap

Comment: So you already know, why the behavior is as observed. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps): *"The selected and clear bitmaps should be **monochrome**. [...] **If you use color bitmaps, the results may be undesirable**."* Anyway, this is using the wrong tool. You'll want to use [SetMenuItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuiteminfow) instead. [Using Menus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/using-menus) is also very helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable
I tried the code
    `MENUITEMINFO mii;`
    `mii.fMask = MIIM_CHECKMARKS;`
    `mii.hbmpChecked = *bitmapArray.GetAt(iItem);`
    `mii.hbmpUnchecked = *bitmapArray.GetAt(iItem);`
    `pMenu->SetMenuItemInfo(iItem, &mii, TRUE);`
but still not working
thank you very much

Comment: I was under the impression, that you wish to set icons to your menu items, but your code consistently attempts to show *checkmarks*. Which one do you need? Unclear from your question, as the question really only talks about issues with extracting bitmaps from an image list (which apparently is not even related to your issue).

Comment: @IInspectable
you are right, I wish to set icons to my menu items.
and since i don't know where is the problem is (in the loading of the imagelist or in getting a specific image or in the setting menu icon) so i wrote the complete code.

Comment: Use the `MIIM_BITMAP` mask, and populate the `hbmpItem` member.

Comment: @IInspectable
I did but no icons in the menu :(

Comment: Probably because you didn't mark the menu item as showing a bitmap (`MF_BITMAP`). [Using Menus: Using Menu-Item Bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/using-menus#using-menu-item-bitmaps) has general guidelines. It's impossible to tell what's wrong, since your question is asking about an issue, that's neither an issue nor related to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I normally create the image list as a member variable of the class and not local to the function. I will try to dig out my code for doing menu item bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is how I actually do it:

## Step 1

I have a variable define din my class:

```
MenuBitmapsMap m_mapMenuBitmap;
```

This is in the header:

```
using MenuBitmapsMap = map<UINT, CBitmap>;
```

## Step 2

I have this method in my class:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::AddMenuBitmaps()
{
    CMenu*pMenu = GetMenu();

    if (pMenu == nullptr)
        return;

    m_mapMenuBitmap.clear(); 

    // File menu
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_SAVE, IDB_BMP_MENU_SAVE);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_SAVEASFILE, IDB_BMP_MENU_SAVE_AS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_PRINT, IDB_BMP_MENU_PRINT);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_IMPORT_FROM_OCLM_ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY, IDB_BMP_MENU_IMPORT);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_EXPORT, IDB_BMP_MENU_EXPORT);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_EXPORTSETTINGS, IDB_BMP_MENU_SETTINGS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, IDB_BMP_MENU_PRINT_PREVIEW);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_FILE_AVAILABILITY_REPORT, IDB_BMP_MENU_REPORT);

    // Auto menu
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_AUTO_ASSIGN, IDB_BMP_MENU_AUTO_ASSIGN);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_SELECTED_COLUMN, IDB_BMP_MENU_COLUMNS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_SETTINGS, IDB_BMP_MENU_SETTINGS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_CLEAR_ASSIGNMENTS, IDB_BMP_MENU_CLEAR);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_SELECTED_COLUMN, IDB_BMP_MENU_COLUMNS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_EXCLUSIONS, IDB_BMP_MENU_EXCLUSIONS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_SELECTED_COLUMN, IDB_BMP_MENU_COLUMNS);
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_AUTOASSIGN_SHOW_CONFLICTS, IDB_BMP_MENU_HIGHLIGHT);

    // Help menu
    UpdateMenuBitmap(pMenu, ID_HELP_HELP, IDB_BMP_MENU_HELP);

}
```

The above method is called in `OnInitDialog`.

## Step 3

This is the definition for `UpdatemenuBitmap`:

```
void CCreateReportDlg::UpdateMenuBitmap(CMenu *pMenu, UINT uCommandID, UINT uBMPResource,
    bool bByPosition /*false*/, bool bDisabled /*false*/)
{
    if (pMenu == nullptr)
        return;

    // We are working on the "actual" bitmap object held in the map
    CBitmap& bitmap = m_mapMenuBitmap[uCommandID];
    if (bitmap.GetSafeHandle() != nullptr)
        bitmap.DeleteObject();
    if (bitmap.LoadBitmap(uBMPResource) == NULL)
        return;

    theApp.SetBitmapBackgroundAsMenuColour(bitmap);
    if (bDisabled)
        theApp.SetBitmapAsGrayScale(bitmap);

    if (!pMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(uCommandID,
        bByPosition ? MF_BYPOSITION : MF_BYCOMMAND,
        &bitmap,
        &bitmap))
    {
        // #UpdateMenuBitmap Failed to set the menu item bitmaps
    }
}
```

I have not supplied the other two methods because they don't directly relate to your question I don't think. I can add then to the answer if required.

When you look at the documentation for [`SetMenuItemBitmaps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps) it states:

> When the menu is destroyed, these bitmaps are **not destroyed**; it is up to the application to destroy them.

In your code you are creating the `CImageList` inside the method. Add it as a **member variable** instead so that the object **remains valid** for when the menus are displayed. 
Then, destroy your image list in `OnDestroy` (might not be required for resource images).

## Update

Here are the extra methods which I have in the app class:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetBitmapBackgroundAsMenuColour(HBITMAP hbmp)
{
    UpdateBitmapBackground(hbmp, true);
}


void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetBitmapAsGrayScale(HBITMAP hbmp)
{
    UpdateBitmapBackground(hbmp, false);
}

void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::UpdateBitmapBackground(HBITMAP hbmp, bool enabled, COLORREF crBackground /* GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU) */)
{
    if (!hbmp)
        return;
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);

    BITMAP bm;
    ::GetObject(hbmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    int w = bm.bmWidth;
    int h = bm.bmHeight;
    BITMAPINFO bi = { sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), w, h, 1, 32, BI_RGB };

    std::vector<uint32_t> pixels(w * h);
    GetDIBits(memdc, hbmp, 0, h, &pixels[0], &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    //assume that the color at (0,0) is the background color
    uint32_t old_color = pixels[0];

    //this is the new background color
    uint32_t bk = crBackground;

    //swap RGB with BGR
    uint32_t new_color = RGB(GetBValue(bk), GetGValue(bk), GetRValue(bk));

    //define lambda functions to swap between BGR and RGB
    auto bgr_r = [](uint32_t color) { return GetBValue(color); };
    auto bgr_g = [](uint32_t color) { return GetGValue(color); };
    auto bgr_b = [](uint32_t color) { return GetRValue(color); };

    BYTE new_red = bgr_r(new_color);
    BYTE new_grn = bgr_g(new_color);
    BYTE new_blu = bgr_b(new_color);

    //change background and modify disabled bitmap
    for (auto &p : pixels)
    {
        if (p == old_color)
        {
            p = new_color;
        }
        else if (!enabled)
        {
            //blend color with background, similar to 50% alpha
            BYTE red = (bgr_r(p) + new_red) / 2;
            BYTE grn = (bgr_g(p) + new_grn) / 2;
            BYTE blu = (bgr_b(p) + new_blu) / 2;
            p = RGB(blu, grn, red); //<= BGR/RGB swap
        }
    }

    //fix corner edges
    for (int row = h - 2; row >= 1; row--)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col < w - 1; col++)
        {
            int i = row * w + col;
            if (pixels[i] != new_color)
            {
                //check the color of neighboring pixels:
                //if that pixel has background color,
                //then that pixel is the background 

                bool l = pixels[i - 1] == new_color; //left pixel is background
                bool r = pixels[i + 1] == new_color; //right  ...
                bool t = pixels[i - w] == new_color; //top    ...
                bool b = pixels[i + w] == new_color; //bottom ...

                                                     //we are on a corner pixel if:
                                                     //both left-pixel and top-pixel are background or
                                                     //both left-pixel and bottom-pixel are background or
                                                     //both right-pixel and bottom-pixel are background or
                                                     //both right-pixel and bottom-pixel are background
                if (l && t || l && b || r && t || r && b)
                {
                    //blend corner pixel with background
                    BYTE red = (bgr_r(pixels[i]) + new_red) / 2;
                    BYTE grn = (bgr_g(pixels[i]) + new_grn) / 2;
                    BYTE blu = (bgr_b(pixels[i]) + new_blu) / 2;
                    pixels[i] = RGB(blu, grn, red);//<= BGR/RGB swap
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SetDIBits(memdc, hbmp, 0, h, &pixels[0], &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
unfortunately, it isn't working with me.
i moved `CImageList` to the class member variables, but the same result.
the idea of using `CImageList` is that it creates the bitmaps with a mask color
if i cut the image that has all the icons into many bitmaps resources, it displays the icons but with the mask color around the icon. do you know a way to load the bitmap with a mask color?
thanks again

Comment: @AmirYouhana This is why I have `SetBitmapBackgroundAsMenuColour`. It takes the first pixel replaces all of those pixels with the menu colour. I have not used masks. Sorry.

Comment: OK Andrew. 
where is the implementation of the function `SetBitmapBackgroundAsMenuColour(bitmap)`